# access object inside nested event binding javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Am trying to bind an audio replay event inside an audio ended event. I couldn't access the actual parent object to which i have audio ended event attached to.

```
var audio = new Audio('audiofile.mp3');
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    $("#replayButton").bind('click', function(){
        audio.play(); //why i couldn't access the audio object
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a variable in the outer function:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    var self = this;
    $("#replayButton").bind('click', function(){
        self.play(); //why i couldn't access the audio object
    });
});
```

However, binding an event handler inside another event handler is usually not a good idea. When you replay the audio, when it ends you'll bind another click handler. So if the user clicks the replay button again, it will start it playing twice.

The `.one()` method might be more appropriate for this, so the `click` handler only runs once after each time it ends. So it should be:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    var self = this;
    $("#replayButton").one('click', function(){
        self.play(); //why i couldn't access the audio object
    });
});
```

Comment: what if i use unbind after i click on the replay ? so in that case i have only one function boundto it right ?

Comment: That's essentially what `.one()` does.